# Scala Play 2.5 Turning an Action into A Result

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

In a Play scala project, I'm returning an object inside of a Controller with the type:

`play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.libs.json.JsValue` however, play is complaining that it is expecting `play.api.mvc.Result`. According to the docs, an Action is a function that handles a request and generates a result.

```
def myController = mySpecialFunction.asyc(prase.tolerantJson) { implicit request => {
        for {
            ... do some stuff ...
        } yield {
            myFunction()
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, myFunction has a return type of `play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.libs.json.JsValue`.

I want to return a result, and I'm not sure how to correctly call this function

Comment: Typically, an action is what you define as the top-level function(s) in a controller. Play will invoke the action passing it a request and expecting you to return a result. Why do you have a variable `myController`? Typically, you'd a have a class that represents your controller and then a number of methods inside that class that represent the actions. If you want to just make the code work as it is, you'll have to apply the request to the `myFunction` -- however as I said this looks rather odd.

Comment: Can probably help you more if you can show what `myFunction` does at high level. As you have stated yourself, your Action is not designed as well it could be. Also, note that `Action.async` requires you to return a `Future[Result]` not just a `Result`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Action.async`  block expects a function from `request` to `Future[Result]`.

Now, your `myFunction()` is inside the `yield` block returning `JsValue` as return type. If your for comprehension is on Futures, then the output of the for-comprehension becomes `Future[JsValue]`. But play expects `Future[Result]`. Transform your result into `Future[Result]`. So that your final output type should be `Future[Result]`.

for example

```
Action.async { req =>
  val resultFuture = 
    for {
      _ <- getUsersFuture
      _ <- doSomethingFuture
    } yield (myFunction)

  resultFuture.map { json => Ok(json) }
}
```

Comment: The return value of `myFunction()` inside the `yield` is `Action[JsValue]`, not just `JsValue`

Comment: I think it's an overall design problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve the problem as-is, you can pass request to the result of `myFunction()`:

```
def myController = mySpecialFunction.asyc(prase.tolerantJson) { implicit request => {
        for {
            ... do some stuff ...
        } yield {
            myFunction()(request)
        }
    }
}
```

This works because there is a method `Action#apply` which will be invoked with the `request` instance and return a `Future[Result]`.

The documentation for the `apply` method: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Action